# How can I add the ActionEvent to the JButton so that when i click it it will fire the event?

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to add the ActionListener to the JButton but cannot seem to get it to work properly.

I have tried to add the ActionListeneer and also the ActionEvent and neither seems to fire the ActionPerformed method.

I did not one curious aspect was the the compiler made me take off the @Override keyword since the interface is used to create a variable and not implemented.

Does this make a difference? I am certain that you can do it this way but I think I am just a bit off the mark.

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class testInterfaces2 {
    static ActionListener m;
    static ActionEvent me;

    testInterfaces2() {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");

         f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);
            }
         });

         JButton pButton = new JButton("Print");
         pButton.addActionListener(m);
         //pButton.addActionListener(m.actionPerformed(me));

         f.add("Center", pButton);
         f.pack();
         f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class name should begin with an upper case letter, and in fact all Java classes should follow this rule, while variable and method names should begin with a lower case letter. This might seem like nitpicking, but it becomes important whenever you wish to share your code with others, since by following Java naming conventions, others will be able to understand your code quicker and much more completely.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this and remove `ActionListener` and `ActionEvent` variables that is not needed.

```
public class testInterfaces2 implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
    }

    ...
    JButton pButton = new JButton("Print");
    pButton.addActionListener(this); 
}
```

1. `@Override` doesn't do any thing extra other than **compile time checking** of the overridden method.
2. In simple term, You need a class that implements `ActionListener` and obviously implements `actionPerformed()` method. Simply create a object of that class and pass in `addActionListener()` method.

Comment: Or you could create an instance of ActionListener and assign it to m ;)

Comment: Yes that's my last statement.

Comment: Can you show the code for this. MadProgrammer is thinking what I am thinking. I am certain of it. MadProgrammer could you show a working example of this. I think you are thinking what I am thinking. I was trying to see if you could make the same example without having to implement an interface. When you say create an instance of ActionListener and assign it to m are you saying ActionListener myList = m; or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

> I did not one curious aspect was the the compiler made me take off the
>   @Override keyword since the interface is used to create a variable and
>   not implemented.

This should have highlighted your first problem, your `testInterfaces2` class can't override `actionPerformed` as it's not defined in any part of the parent class or it's parents.  This is because  `testInterfaces2` doesn't implement `ActionListener` directly or indirectly (via inheritance).

Your second problem is `m` is `null`, you've never initialised it

Take a closer look at [How to write ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to define a new ActionListener for each button. Like this

```
JButton pButton = new JButton();

pButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```